# Outlook 2010 Inbox window does not open

Tags: windows-7, email, microsoft-outlook-2010, window, exchange-2010

I know this question has been asked before but none of the solutions offered fixed my user's situation.

> current environment

Windows 7 Enterprise x64

Outlook 2010 x64 client

Microsoft Exchange 2010 Server

> What happens after a complete reboot

Click Outlook icon in taskbar

splash window appears and does it's thing

taskbar icon and notification bar icon appears

**inbox window does not appear**

reminders window does appear and I can even right-click the taskbar icon and open the new email/meeting/appointment dialog.

> What I have tried

Rebuild of outlook profile by renaming appdata/local/outlook folder to outlook.old

full repair of Office Pro Plus 2010 program from Programs and Features

checked `HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Current Version\Explorer\Shell Folders` and `HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Current Version\Explorer\User Shell Folders` for a misspelled Appdata folder as was suggested in [Outlook 2010: Can't open the Outlook window](https://superuser.com/questions/200235/outlook-2010-cant-open-the-outlook-window) but I did not find anything out of place.

---

Currently the only way I can completely open Outlook with the Inbox window is using `outlook.exe /safe`.

My next step that I will try is to completely reinstall Office 2010 and see if it makes a difference. If there's no change, I'm going to tell the guy to back up his stuff so I can reimage the whole machine.

Comment: Have you tried to sign on with another account on the same PC to see if there's an issue with that account and Outlook there as well? It may be a corrupt Windows 7 user profile issue I suppose as well. It starts up in Safe mode so that means in regular mode something may just be loading that causes the issue. Are you able to get to the add-ons in safe mode and see if you can disable any?

Comment: Completely reinstalled Office 2010 Pro Plus. Also tried adding my own email account. it launches the process and puts an .ost in the appdata/local/microsoft/outlook folder but the inbox window still doesn't launch. No change whatsoever with either of these fixes.

Comment: Have you tried logging onto the PC with a different login though? Sign on with a completely different login at the Windows OS level and then see what happens with it's Outlook profile. This should tell you if it's a Windows OS user account corrupt profile issue. Were you able to look in Safe mode in Outlook to see a list of add-ons, etc.?

Comment: Go to “File Tab->Options->Addins->" Select “COM Add-ins".  in the Manage drop-down at the bottom of the “Options->Addins” window and click “Go”.

Comment: Tried disabling all these add-ons and restarting outlook. no change. 
http://i.imgur.com/5Zwv5bo.png

one interesting note is I wasn't able to deselect the RSADLP add-in. whenever I would relaunch it would have that one selected. I had to actually remove it to keep it from running.

Comment: Wonder if that RSA Add-in is still doing that or even shows on the new Outlook profile? Glad to hear you found the solution regardless just suggesting things I've tried in the past for this issue at this level.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a possible cause to my problem. As @1Fish_2Fish_RedFish_BlueFish suggested, I loaded up my Windows profile on the users machine and was able to open outlook right away. Will attempt to rebuild the users account and see if that fixes it.

Thanks for the assistance!

Update: Rebuilding the users Windows profile fixed the issue.

Answer (score -1):

I have had this a few times, frustrating. Tried turning of PC, re-starting, but rarely clear the fault. This worked for me, and simple. So sharing

[image]